# Substracting two unsigned integers and getting the result's absolute value

Tags: c

I have two unsigned integers, a and b. Now my goal is to get the absolute value of the difference between the two.

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
uint64_t a, b;
llabs((int64_t)(a - b))
```

This *seems* to work, however I'm not sure if it is. Could anyone confirm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, for some values there is a problem: I. e. for `a=0` and `b` greater than the maximum value of `int64_t+1` you will have an overflow. I do not know, whether your real world values can be that way.

However, you can have it much easier:

```
a>b?a-b:b-a
```

Comment: Yeah the workarounds aren't the issue, I was just wondering if that would work correctly. I'm slightly unfamiliar with unsigned ints. An explanation of why that would overflow be would be appreciated if you have the time!

Comment: First of all, if b>a the subtraction will have a negative result. This is a problem, because unsigned integers cannot contain a negative value. (This is what makes them unsigned.) However, there are some rules for the behavior of unsigned overflows and casting to signed values as you did. And however, since it is common to use 2th complement it will work in real world. But the negative range of signed integers is half of the range of unsigned integers. Therefore you can create a negative result, which cannot be hold by a signed integer.

Comment: Let's have an example of a 3 bit integer. Unsigned values have the range of 0…7. Signed integers have the range of +3…-4. It is clear that the unsigned subtraction can create a value that is outside the range of the signed integer you cast to.

Comment: !? As in my answer!?